# Custom formatter for Sun Codemodel

Tags: java, code-generation, code-formatting, sun-codemodel

I'm using [Java Sun Codemodel](https://codemodel.java.net/) to generate java classes on the fly, and it works pretty well for me.

Now I have an additional challenge: How do I control how the code is formatted? Is there any way at all? In particular, I'd like to have all curly brackets in a new line and would like to extend the line length to let's say 130 chars.

E.g., we have a formatter that we use in Eclipse. There's no way I can just tell Codemodel to use that somehow, right?

There's this [JFormatter](https://codemodel.java.net/nonav/apidocs/com/sun/codemodel/JFormatter.html) class that kind of looks like it could be useful for something, but it doesn't look like it can do more sophisticated stuff like that.

Answer (score 1):

JFormatter declared as final, so not, it isn't possible.

There's only two ways to solve the problem and continue using codemodel.

1. Process generated code with some another tool/library.
2. Redefine library classes. Find which concrete classes does unwanted formatting, then create classes with same package/name in your project and write your own implementation. There classes must appear in classpath earlier than codemodel jar.